# Standard Deviation of Differences of elements in a finite subset of countable set?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

How do we calculate the standard deviation of countable set $A$ by taking the deviation of finite set $A_i$ where $A_i\subseteq A_{i+1}$ and $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}\bigcup\limits_{i\le j}A_i=A$.

For example, if we have set $A=\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}}\cap[0,1]$ and we set $A_i=\left\{\sqrt{m}/\sqrt{n}:m\in\mathbb{N},n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0},m\le n<j\right\}$ arrange the elements in $A_i$ from the least to greatest and take the difference of consecutive pairs of elements. This gives $B_i$. As $j$ grows larger what would the standard deviation of $\lim\limits_{j\to\infty}\bigcup\limits_{i\le j}B_i$ converge to. (Try to do analytically but if this is not possible use programming. I already tried but I want to check my answer with yours).

Comment: If programming is allowed then what is preventing you from doing it ? (This seems to be a very hard problem from an analytical point of view, because of the rearrangement part).

Comment: @nicomezi I was wondering if this could be done analytically but if not you can use programming. I already tried using programming but I want to make sure my answer is correct.